# Return name of created file from decoded string in php

Tags: php, file-upload, utf-8

Hi i have the following code to decode and save image

```
$photo = $_REQUEST['image'];
$binary = base64_decode ($photo);
header ('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen ('uploads/'.time().'.png', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose ($file);
```

This works fine but i will like to get the name of the image after it is written and store that name as a variable to use in the rest of the code where it will be saved in mysql database. I can write to mysql i just need to get the file name. Thanks

Comment: Make `'uploads/'.time().'.png'` a variable first, then use it in the `fopen`. You then will have it a variable as well.

Comment: exactly. Common sense, you got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already naming the file yourself. Just store it in a variable before you write the file.

```
$filename = time().'.png';
$file = fopen ('uploads/'.$filename, 'wb');
```